# overwrite let inside an it method to alter params send to subject

Tags: ruby, rspec

It's possible to overwrite a `let` value inside an spec? I wanted to be able to set subject and modify my params within each test, something like:

```
  subject {
    MyClass.new params
  }

  let(:params) { {} }

  describe '#initialize' do
    it 'should set new params' do
      params = {a: 1}
      expect{ subject }.to do_something
    end
    it 'should raise with string' do
      params = 'string'
      expect{ subject }.to raise_error
    end
  end
```

or what is the correct way to approach this? should I wrote my `expect{}` with the whole class name?

Comment: I would just put the MyClass.new in each test case, or move it to a helper function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite the specs like this:

```
subject { -> { MyClass.new(params) } } # Note: subject is a lambda

describe '#initialize' do
  context 'with blank params' do
    let(:params) { {} }
    it { is_expected.to do_something }
  end

  context 'with string params' do
    let(:params) { 'string' }
    it { is_expected.to raise_error }
  end
end
```

But - as max pleaner already said - in this simple example it would probably be more readable and maintainable to skip the `subject` and just use the `MyClass.new ...` call directly in the expectation

Comment: The OP used the block syntax of RSpec. IMO this can only be translated into the one-liner syntax if the subject is a lambda.

Comment: Because `expect( subject).to` works differently than `expect{ subject }.to`. The first translates to `is { expected_to ...`, the second does not and instead would stop because of the raised error.  `expect( subject)` specs the return value of the expression, `expect{ subject } the side effects. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/805)

Comment: Yes, you were right all along and I misunderstood your point. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/805. This appears to be the drawback of `is_expected.to` syntax. I myself almost never use it.

Comment: If you want you can add part of my answer to yours: in this case I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Ilya Thanks, but I think it depends on what `do_something` does. The question is not clear and it makes a difference if the OP wants to have an expectation of a side effect or the return value. My answer works if the OP is interested in the side effect, your when it is about the return value. Therefore I think both answers make sense at the moment.